# cannot correctly view of carousel using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to view a carousel on bootstrap. I can view the images
but the image does not proceed to the next image. I want to view also the caption 
below the images.

thanks

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item"><img src="sample1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="item"><img src="sample2.jpg"/></div>
<div class="item"><img src="sample3.jpg"/></div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following javascript to cycle the carousel,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000,
        wrap: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. it worked. Ahm, can I asked what does wrap mean?

Comment: "Wrap - Whether the carousel should cycle continuously or have hard stops." If my answer help you, please mark as answer